# order of an element formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was wondering whether there's a formula or something. If it is given that $x^n = e$ and $x^m = e$, does it mean $x^{gcd(n,m)} = e$, so we can determine whether $x=e$ or $x \ne e$?

Comment: I'm not sure what one might would hope for in a formula: in general, groups can be pretty bizarre. Anyway, it seems unlikely that in practice you'll have easier access to any information than to the order of an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no set formula, but we do know that the order of the element must divide the order of the group by Lagrange's theorem.  For certain groups, determining the order of an element can be easy.  For example, any $k$-cycle in $S_n$ has order $k$.

Also, $x^m = e$ if $x^n = e$, then we know $x^{m-n} = e$ and $x^{gcd(m, n)} = e$.

Further, if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, then $x = e$.

Comment: You mean, for example, if $gcd(m,n) = 2$, then we definitely know $x \ne e$?

Comment: No.  The converse is not true.  Consider $m=6$ and $n=4$.  Then $x^6 = x^4 \Rightarrow x^2 = e$.  In this case, $x$ *could* be $e$.